# Extract each occurrence of a string into a separate line to build a list of URLs

Tags: emeditor

I would like to extract all occurrences of a URL string pattern (which can appear multiple times in a file) to build a list of all occurrences.
Currently I can identify each occurrence with the Find in files feature, but I would like the Extract feature to list each occurrence on a new line. Currently the feature lists each line that contains the string. And a line can contain the sting multiple times.
My goal is to get a list of the full URL that contains __data/assets/

In the below example  __data/assets/  occurs 48 times.
However, the extract only 44 lines are extracted, but I need to output all 48 occurrences (the full URL).
I will be running this extract over 270 files in total.

View source of this example webpage:
https://www.walkerville.sa.gov.au/council/strategic-plans/2020-2024-living-in-the-town-of-walkerville-a-strategic-community-plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that all URLs are surrounded by double quotation marks.

If so, you can search for a regular expression:

`[^\"]*__data/assets/[^\"]*`

and select **Display Matched Strings Only** in the **Extract Options** dialog box.

Comment: That worked a treat. Thank you, very much appreciated.